# SQL Server 2008 simple recovery mode issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

During my daily maintenance backup task, I am attempting to set specific databases to recovery model simple along with shrinking the database.

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
GO
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (db_name)
GO
```

This happens at 1am along with some other tasks that use the same database. However, I am getting an error where

> Execute T-SQL Statement Task (AERIS\SQL2008) Execute TSQL on Local server connection   Execution time out: 0 Task start:  2011-12-08T01:00:04.
>   Task end: 2011-12-08T01:16:45.
>   Failed:(-1073548784) Executing the query
>   "alter database db_name set recovery simple" failed with the following error: "ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be
>   placed on database 'db_name'. Try again later.
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly,
>   parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Could the issue be that since a user is logged on the the server at the point the recovery model is being changed? I'm puzzled since sometimes the recovery model change works intermittently.

Comment: The error just means that the query couldn't put an exclusive lock on the database to change the recovery model, so that means someone or something else was still connected to that database

Answer (score 3):

If you change the recovery model to SIMPLE to back to either FULL or BULK_RECOVERY you make all your transaction log backups useless.  The recovery model shouldn't every be changed regularly.

Shrinking the database is simply fragmenting all the objects within the database tables.

You should stop doing both of these things.

Comment: As a followup, please read the following blog posts: http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/Misconceptions.aspx

Answer (score -3):

You have to restart the database server after a change of recovery model , so what you are doing isn't going to work anyway.

Why are you shrinking on a daily basis anyway, it's at best a complete waste of time in nearly all cases.

Comment: We do this on our testing databases on a daily basis in order to keep down the transaction logs.

Comment: Changing the recovery model does NOT require restarting the SQL Instance.